# Audio injector codec board wm8731 bcm2835-i2s 20203000.i2s: I2S SYNC error! raspberry pi b+

Tags: raspbian, audio, audio-playback

I'm using raspberry pi b+ and audio injector codec board wm8731.

I changed in `boot/config.txt` file  and added `dtoverlay=audioinjector-wm8731-audio`, but after reboot `lsmod` shows drivers but `aplay` and `arecord` are not  working.

error like:

```
[    7.482939] audioinjector-audio soc:sound: ASoC: CODEC DAI wm8731-hifi not registered - will retry
[    7.482970] audioinjector-audio soc:sound: snd_soc_register_card failed (-517)
[    9.164701] systemd-journald[117]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   10.439748] wm8731 1-001a: Assuming static MCLK
[   10.439789] 1-001a supply AVDD not found, using dummy regulator
[   10.441207] 1-001a supply HPVDD not found, using dummy regulator
[   10.441364] 1-001a supply DCVDD not found, using dummy regulator
[   10.441478] 1-001a supply DBVDD not found, using dummy regulator
[   10.460035] audioinjector-audio soc:sound: wm8731-hifi <-> 20203000.i2s mapping ok
[   16.885190] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
[   19.050634] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   20.664648] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
[   27.732131] random: crng init done
[   31.402168] bcm2835-i2s 20203000.i2s: I2S SYNC error!
[   31.832918] bcm2835-i2s 20203000.i2s: I2S SYNC error!
[   31.973635] bcm2835-i2s 20203000.i2s: I2S SYNC error!
[   32.062855] bcm2835-i2s 20203000.i2s: I2S SYNC error!
[ 1809.728867] bcm2835-i2s 20203000.i2s: I2S SYNC error!
[ 1809.730148] bcm2835-i2s 20203000.i2s: I2S SYNC error!
[ 1811.588596] bcm2835-dma 20007000.dma: DMA transfer could not be terminated

 **aplay error:**
aplay: pcm_write:1939: write error: Input/output error
```

aplay hangs while playing wave file

I'm using 3.5 mm jack with earphone for listening.

Please suggest any way to use audio injector card on raspberry pi b+

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you are using the stereo Audio Injector card and not the Octo 8 channel card. This line :

```
audioinjector-audio soc:sound: wm8731-hifi <-> 20203000.i2s mapping ok
```

shows that ALSA has set up your audio injector card correctly.
The "I2S SYNC error!" lines are part of the bcm2835 i2s driver and are standard - nothing to worry about.

You should be able to see the audio injector sound card when you type aplay -l
Similarly alsamixer will give you the mixer settings and allow you to change them.

If you have onging issues, the Audio Injector cards have a support site [forum.audioinjector.net](http://forum.audioinjector.net)

Comment: Great..!!!!!!!!!!! i got it working bu changing few parameters using alsamixer

Comment: I had the same problem with an AudioInjector card, and I needed to enable (unmute) the "Output Mixer HiFi" toggle. Thanks!